# Xen command xl doesn't create a vm but xend/xm does

Tags: virtualization, xen

I'm a newbie to Xen, and I've recently installed Xen 4.2 by sources on my system.
I've found a strange thing I've a VM when I start it via the command "xm create machine.cfg" all work fine, but if I use "xl create machine.cfg" it gives me the following error

> xc: error: panic: xc_dom_core.c:442: xc_dom_alloc_segment: segment ramdisk too large (0x4ba > 0x2000 - 0x1bd9 pages): Out of memory
>   libxl: error: libxl_dom.c:208:libxl__build_pv xc_dom_build_image failed: Invalid argument
>   cannot (re-)build domain: -3
>   xenconsole: Could not read tty from store: No such file or directory

What could be the problem? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently I've solved the problem simply adding the memory specification in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your system seems to complain about too few RAM being available for your new VM which is started with the configuration file "machine.cfg".
(I assume that machine.cfg and macchina.cfg differ from each other and are not the same.)

Comment: No I made a typo. I edited the question.

Comment: I suggest to run strace -f -e trace=open xl create machine.cfg and look if really your desired config file is being used.

Comment: I did, but it seems that it's seeing the correct file infact it's loading the correct kernel and initrd.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your DOM0 have installed kernel version apropiated for the VM version if not install the needed version for the DOMU in the boot directory of DOM0.